# reading arbitrary dataset data returned from asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ado.net, dataset

I'm new to asp.net web api.
I've written a method that calls a stored procedure and gets a dataset back thru the enterprise library data access application block. I want to consume that from an asp.net webforms application (all .net 4.5/visual studio 2013). I want to be able to do this for any stored procedure I have that returns a dataset without writing a specific class for the dataset or the specific json object or whatever that I can convert it to.

I've found examples of doing this with custom classes like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
}
```

where Product is some class representing a product.
I assume this code could be easily modified to get an ado.net DataSet instance or XML or a JSON representation of a DataSet without writing a custom class like Product to accept the data but I haven't figured that out or found it yet. An example would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a string representation of the HTTPContent you can do `string jsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` This will return the content in whatever string format it was serialized in by the client. With this json formatted string I assume you could read that into your ado.net dataset object.